# Would it be more correct to say "active winter holidays" or "winter activity holidays"?

Tags: british-english, phrase-usage

I have seen both phrases used by tourism websites. Are both correct?

Comment: Both are nonsensical.

Comment: I suppose those websites were designed poorly.

Comment: They mean different things. What is the specific source of your confusion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two phrases have different meanings. "Active winter holidays" are active holidays that take place in the winter. Mountain biking trips in January (N. hemisphere) would be one example, where the activity can take place all year round. Skiing and snowboarding are winter activities, and may be done on "winter activity holidays".